# useState() bug - state value different from initial value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I have a component that uses `useState()` to handle the state of its floating label, like this:

```
const FloatingLabelInput = props => {
  const {
    value = ''
  } = props

  const [floatingLabel, toggleFloatingLabel] = useState(value !== '')
```

I have a series of those components and you'd expect `initialFloatingLabel` and `floatingLabel` to always be the same, but they're not for some of them! I can see by logging the values:

```
const initialFloatingLabel = value !== ''
console.log(initialFloatingLabel) // false
const [floatingLabel, toggleFloatingLabel] = useState(initialFloatingLabel)
console.log(floatingLabel) // true???
```

And it's a consistent result. How is that possible?

How come `value` can be different from `initialValue` in the following example? Is it a sort of race condition?

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)
```

More details [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16761)

**UPDATE**

This ([as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57908129/795398)) fixes the problem:

```
useEffect(() => setFloatingLabel(initialFloatingLabel), [initialFloatingLabel])
```

...but it creates another one: if I focus on a field, type something and then delete it until the value is an empty string, it will "unfloat" the label, like this (the label should be floating):

[image]

I didn't intend to update the `floatingLabel` state according to the input `value` at all times; the value of `initialFloatingLabel` was only meant to dictate the initial value of the toggle, and I'd toggle it on `handleBlur` and `handleChange` events, like this:

```
const handleFocus = e => {
  toggleFloatingLabel(true)
}

const handleBlur = e => {
  if (value === '') {
    toggleFloatingLabel(false)
  }
}
```

Is this approach wrong?

**UPDATE**

I keep finding new solutions to this but there's always a persisting problem and I'd say it's an issue with Formik - it seems to initially render all my input component from its render props function before the values are entirely computed from Formik's `initialValues`.

For example:

I added another local state which I update on the `handleFocus` and `handleBlur`:

```
const [isFocused, setFocused] = useState(false)
```

so I can then do this to prevent unfloating the label when the input is empty but focused:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const shouldFloat = value !== '' && !isFocused
    setFloatLabel(shouldFloat)
  }, [value])
```

I'd still do this to prevent pre-populated fields from having an animation on the label from non-floating to floating (I'm using `react-spring` for that):

```
const [floatLabel, setFloatLabel] = useState(value !== '')
```

But I'd still get an animation on the label (from "floating" to "non-floating") on those specific fields I pointed out in the beginning of this thread, which aren't pre-populated.

Following the suggestion from the comments, I ditched the `floatingLabel` local state entirely and just kept the `isFocused` local state. That's great, I don't really need that, and I can only have this for the label animation:

```
const animatedProps = useSpring({
    transform: isFocused || value !== '' ? 'translate3d(0,-13px,0) scale(0.66)' : 'translate3d(0,0px,0) scale(1)',
    config: {
      tension: 350,
    },
  })
```

The code looks cleaner now but I still have the an animation on the label when there shouldn't be (for those same specific values I mentioned at the start), because `value !== ''` equals to `true` for *some obscure reason* at a first render and then to `false` again.

Am I doing something wrong with Formik when setting the initial values for the fields?

Comment: Can you create a codepen to reproduce this?

Comment: `floatingLabel` is derived from `props.value`; why do you need state at all? Would `const floatingLabel = props.value !== '';` be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

You have the use `useEffect` to update your state when `initialFloatingLabel` change.

```
const initialFloatingLabel = value !== ''
const [floatingLabel, setFloatingLabel] = useState(initialFloatingLabel)

// calling the callback when initialFloatingLabel change
useEffect(() => setFloatingLabel(initialFloatingLabel), [initialFloatingLabel])

...
```

Your problem look like prop drilling issue. Perhaps you should store `floatingLabel` in a `context`.

```
// floatingLabelContext.js
import { createContext } from 'react'

export default createContext({})

// top three component
...
import { Provider as FloatingLabelProvider } from '../foo/bar/floatingLabelContext'

const Container = () => {
  const [floatingLabel, setFloatingLabel] = useState(false)
  return (
    <FloatingLabelProvider value={{ setFloatingLabel, floatingLabel }}>
      <SomeChild />
    </FloatingLabel>
  )
}

//  FloatingLabelInput.js
import FloatingLabelContext from '../foo/bar/floatingLabelContext'

const FloatingLabelInput = () => {
  const { setFloatingLabel, floatingLabel } = useContext(FloatingLabelContext)

  ...
}
```

This way you just have to use the context to change or read the floatingLabel value where you want in your components three.

Comment: he's asking why they are different not how to make them same!

Comment: The `useEffect()` fixes that! But unfortunately it creates another problem, and that's also not how I intend to use the component, but maybe my approach is flawed? Please have a look at my update!